# Recamán Sequence Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I wrote a program that animates the Recamán sequence. It is in uses HTML canvas and JavaScript. I was hoping for some feedback on how it could be improved.

```js
"use strict";

function getMousePos(evt, can) {
  var rect = can.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.x,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.y,
  }
}

function clearAllIntervals() {
  var id = window.setTimeout(() => {}, 0);
  while (id--) {
    window.clearInterval(id);
  }
}

class Arc {
  constructor(x, y, r, ccw) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.ccw = ccw;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x - offset.x, this.y - offset.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI, this.ccw);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}


document.getElementById("stop").onclick = clearAllIntervals;
document.getElementById("zi").onclick = () => {
  scale += 0.25;
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
}
document.getElementById("zo").onclick = () => {
  scale -= 0.25;
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
}
document.getElementById("cls").onclick = () => {
  arcs.splice(0, arcs.length);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
document.getElementById("hm").onclick = () => {
  offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };
}
document.getElementById("anim").onclick = () => {
  var speed = parseInt(document.getElementById("spd").value);
  var size = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
  if (speed && size) {
    draw(speed, size);
  }
};

addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
});
addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  pos = getMousePos(e, canvas);
});
addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  pos = undefined;
});
addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (pos !== undefined) {
    var mouse = getMousePos(e, canvas);
    offset.x += pos.x - mouse.x;
    offset.y += pos.y - mouse.y;
    pos = mouse;
  }
});


const canvas = document.getElementById("disp");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var arcs = [];
var offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };
var pos = undefined;
var scale = 1;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function draw(spd, siz) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  clearAllIntervals();

  var xPos = 0;
  var used = [];
  arcs = [];
  var i = siz;

  var drawNext = () => {
    if (i > 2500) {
      return null;
    }
    let next = xPos - i;
    if (used.includes(next) || next < 1) {
      next = xPos + i;
    }
    let rad = (next - xPos) / 2;
    arcs.push(new Arc(xPos + rad, canvas.height / 2, Math.abs(rad), i / siz % 2 || 0));
    used.push(next);
    xPos = next;
    i += siz;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    arcs.forEach((arc) => {
      arc.draw();
    });
    setTimeout(drawNext, 1000 / spd);
  };

  drawNext();
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
}

#disp {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

#menu input {
  width: 50px;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Recáman Sequence</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <span>Size: <input id="size" type="number" value="10"></span><br><br>
      <span>Speed: <input id="spd" type="number" value="10"></span><br><br>
      <span><button id="anim">Animate</button></span>
      <span><button id="stop">Stop</button></span>
      <span><button id="cls">Clear</button></span><br>
      <span><button id="hm">Home</button></span>
      <span><button id="zi" disabled="true">&#x1f50d;+</button></span>
      <span><button id="zo" disabled="true">&#x1f50d;-</button></span>
    </div>
    <canvas id="disp"></canvas>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/draw.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works best in full-screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround your code in a self invoking anonymous function

`(function(){ /** code here */ })();`

So it does not conflict with any other variables that may have been declared in the same scope.

---

Declare all global variables at the top of your file and within an object wrapper. It'll be easier to handle them later and know where they are located.

```
const data = {
  arcs: [],
  offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  pos: undefined,
  scale: 1
};
```

---

HTML Elements that are called more than once should be stored in their own variable in the global scope of your project.

Change this

```
var speed = parseInt(document.getElementById("spd").value);
var size = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
```

To

```
/** set with all other global variables */
const speedEle = document.getElementById("spd");
const sizeEle = document.getElementById("size");

/** in your method */
var speed = parseInt(speedEle.value);
var size = parseInt(sizeEle.value);
```

---

Store your setTimeout's ids in a global *store* with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Set).

```
const ids = new Set();

function clearAllIntervals() {
  ids.values().map(clearInterval);
  ids.clear();
}
```

and add your ids like so:

`ids.add(setTimeout(drawNext, 1000 / spd));`

---

Don't use `var` use `let` or `const`.

---

Don't use **magic numbers** i.e:

```
if (i > 2500) {
   return null;
}
```

Define the 2500 as a global constant, preferable in the `data` object mentioned before OR (even better) a `config` object for other such variables (makes it easier if you wish to change those numbers later on)

---

Don't use **undefined** as a value of reference. It's cleaner to use `null` instead.

`let pos = null;`

---

Simplify redundant code

```
function canvasSizeHandler(){
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

addEventListener("resize", canvasSizeHandler);
/** on initial start */
canvasSizeHandler();
```